# Get colour of pixel from CCRenderTexture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

So, I am trying to find the location of any pixels on the screen that are a specific colour.

The following code works, but is VERY slow, because I have to iterate over every single pixel co-ordinate, and there are a lot.

Is there any way to improve the following code to make it more efficient?

```
    // Detect the position of all red points in the sprite
    UInt8 data[4];

    CCRenderTexture* renderTexture = [[CCRenderTexture alloc] initWithWidth: mySprite.boundingBox.size.width * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()
                                                                     height: mySprite.boundingBox.size.height * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()
                                                                pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
    [renderTexture begin];
    [mySprite draw];

    for (int x = 0; x < 960; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 640; y++)
        {                
            ccColor4B *buffer = malloc(sizeof(ccColor4B));
            glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
            ccColor4B color = buffer[0];

            if (color.r == 133 && color.g == 215 && color.b == 44)
            {
                NSLog(@"Found the red point at x: %d y: %d", x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    [renderTexture end];
    [renderTexture release];
```

Comment: reading pixels from framebuffer is slow, especially if you do it pixel by pixel. Take the render texture's texture memory and iterate over that without glReadPixel, that ought to be a lot faster!

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Hey mate! How would I go about that? Do you have an example you could share? Then I could mark your response as correct :)

Comment: My mistake, the CCTexture2D doesn't keep a memory buffer, it's all in GL memory anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't malloc your buffer every time, just reuse the same buffer; malloc is slow! Please take a look at Apple's [Memory Usage Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html).

I don't know of any algorithms that can do this any faster, but this might help.

Comment: Okay, that's a good point. How would I go about implementing re-use of the same buffer?

Comment: Just do the malloc once before you start the iteration.

Comment: I just tried that but it doesn't seem to make the iterations any faster. :(

Comment: It was probably optimized by the compiler, which is why you don't see any improvements. How slow is slow? and how are you measuring speed?

Comment: I'm simply just counting the time it takes to do the previous function to do the one after the iteration. It is taking around 3 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) read more than just one pixel at a time. The way to make OpenGL fast, is to pack all your stuff into as few operations as possible. That works both ways (reading and writing to the GPU).

Try reading the whole texture in one call, and finding your red pixels from the resulting array. As below.

Also note, that generally speaking it is a good idea to traverse a bitmap row by row, which means reversing the order of for -loops (y [rows] on the outside, with x on the inside)

```
// Detect the position of all red points in the sprite
ccColor4B *buffer = new ccColor4B[ 960 * 640 ];

CCRenderTexture* renderTexture = [[CCRenderTexture alloc] initWithWidth: mySprite.boundingBox.size.width * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()
                                                                 height: mySprite.boundingBox.size.height * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()
                                                            pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
[renderTexture begin];
[mySprite draw];

glReadPixels(0, 0, 940, 640, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

[renderTexture end];
[renderTexture release];

int i = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < 640; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 960; x++)
    {                            
        ccColor4B color = buffer[i];//the index is equal to y * 940 + x
        ++i;
        if (color.r == 133 && color.g == 215 && color.b == 44)
        {
            NSLog(@"Found the red point at x: %d y: %d", x, y);
        }
    }
}
delete[] buffer;
```